# Xcode 9 changes CRLF to LF ignoring settings

Tags: line-breaks, xcode9

Since I upgraded to Xcode 9 every time I change even one character in the code, whole file gets its line breaks changed (I checked with xxd) and so it looks like I modified the whole file.

My Preferences->Text Editing is set to CLRF (Original line breaks) and yet it changes everything to LF.

I tried deleting "Caches" and "defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode" no luck..

I still have my old Xcode8 in other folder and editor works fine

Comment: I see it happens only on ".mm" files for some reason. Its ok on ".m"

Comment: also on .h files. My prefs: LF line endings but unchecked "convert existing files one save"

Comment: Reported to Apple and bugreport marked as duplicate, so they know it already.

Comment: Also on .cpp files...